# Why doesn't Get-Member give a full list of all properties and methods.

Tags: powershell

I recently discovered that I can access a property for something that isn't listed when running it through get-member.

Here is an example, which I will demonstrate by using a custom psobject.

First, I'll create the hashtable (which I will later use to create the psobject):

```
$MyHashtable = @{'column1'="aaa";
                 'column2'="bbb";
                 'column3'="ccc"
}
```

Now I create my psobject:

```
PS C:\> $MyNewObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $MyHashtable
```

Now if I run this new object through get-member, it shows:

```
PS C:\> $MyNewObject | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
column1     NoteProperty System.String column1=aaa     
column2     NoteProperty System.String column2=bbb     
column3     NoteProperty System.String column3=ccc
```

So far, so good (although I suspect that a property called "PSObject" is missing from the above list, which I am about to demonstrate now).

However if I now do:

```
PS C:\> $MyNewObject.PSObject


Members             : {System.String column1=aaa, System.String column2=bbb, System.String column3=ccc, string ToString()...}
Properties          : {System.String column1=aaa, System.String column2=bbb, System.String column3=ccc}
Methods             : {string ToString(), bool Equals(System.Object obj), int GetHashCode(), type GetType()}
ImmediateBaseObject : 
BaseObject          : 
TypeNames           : {System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject, System.Object}
```

This worked! How is that possible since "PSObject" wasn't listed as a property when we passed the object through Get-Member.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Get-Help Get-Member -Parameter Force

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Get-Member -Force to see all members

> -Force [SwitchParameter]
>       Adds the intrinsic members (PSBase, PSAdapted, PSObject, PSTypeNames) and the 
>       compiler-generated get_ and set_ methods to the display. By default, Get-Member 
>       gets these properties in all views other than "Base" and "Adapted," but it does 
>       not display them.